# How do I adjust the FoV for Metro Last Light?

Tags: metro-last-light

The default FoV is just too narrow.  There was a way you could do this in 2033 but it doesn't seem to work for this game.  How do I change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking around in the web, so far there have been no way to change the FOV slider for Metro Last Light, however this information can change in the days to come and I will update it if it does,

If it interests you, there is a way to change to DX9 if preferred from this article:

> http://www.dsogaming.com/news/metro-last-light-fov-locked-dx9-workaround-aim-assist-enabled-by-default/

UPDATE 1:

The developers mentioned that changing the FOV would in fact change cut scenes, if we take the developers word to heart then there might be no way to change the FOV without altering the "look" of the game itself.

Here's more from the dev post:

> I come bearing FOV news from 4A.
>
> We're aware the community have been asking for a 'Field of View' slider for Metro: Last Light. Unfortunately, this was not as simple a thing to implement as it might appear!
>
> The main reason for maintaining a fixed FOV is because we have 3D elements like the watch and weapon ammo that need to remain visible.
>
> In addition, all the game's first-person cut scenes and cinematics and each and every animation involving Artyom's hands - idle weapon animations, reloads, ladder climbing, melee attacks etc, - were created assuming the same, fixed field of view.
>
> Changing the FOV would break all the cut-scenes and animations - you would be able to see inside Artyom's arms, or they would appear to float in the air in front of you. Or worse.
>
> We had considered offering three FOV pre-sets, but this would still require significant work to re-do every animation, adjust the HUD and UI and other seemingly small but incredibly time consuming tasks.
>
> Even with a wider but still fixed field of view, Artyom's hands would look too far away. We know - we tried.
>
> Game performance is also tied to FOV - the amount of geometric detail we put in each scene has been partly determined by this set FOV, and setting a wider FOV would have a performance impact.
>
> We understand this issue is important to many people, and we have been looking at possible solutions.
>
> In the immediate term - the next title update, due in the next few days will allow you to directly change the FOV in the .cfg files.
>
> This may well trigger a number of issues listed above - you have been warned!
>
> - 4A Games

Looks like you will be able to change the FOV via the .cfg files in the next few days!

Comment: When you can't answer the question, please don't post.

Comment: I did answer the question. The only reason there is no way to change the FOV slider as of now is because the game is a new release. In a few days, there will be a way and I will update my post.

Comment: @Philipp It is better to awnser you can't then not to awnser at all

Comment: This answer isn't "you can't", this anwer is "I don't know, but I will edit when I find out".

Comment: If you read my answer, I actually said that "so far there have been no way to change the FOV slider for Metro Last Light,". In other words, I did say that you can't for the time being.

Comment: that's pretty frigging stupid of them -_-